# Use a variable as a table name in a Alter Table Statement

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to rename and delete tables dinamically using varibles like that:

```
variable new_table varchar2(30);
exec :new_table := 'TABLE_LERO_' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM_DD_YYYY');
ALTER TABLE TABLE_LERO RENAME TO :new_table;
```

But sqlplus complains:

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Can anyone help or explain why this isn´t working and how to alternatively do the same work ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare
   l_newtablename varchar2(50);
begin
   l_newtablename := 'TABLE_LERO_' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM_DD_YYYY');
   execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_LERO RENAME TO ' || l_newtablename;
end;
/
```

Comment: can I mix these statments with simple statments in one .sql file to run in a bat script in terminal?

Comment: you can save this script in file, e.g. rename.sql and run sqlplus like `sqlplus login/pass@yourdb @rename.sql` or add this command into bat file